# Constraint layout with top title, recycler view and bottom button

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to implement a layout, which will contain the top title, recycler view and bottom button.
Looks simple, but I need to have a wrap_content height for constraint layout to make it scalable depending on the content (top title, bottom button and recycler view. All examples that I've already found with match_parent value. Also, I need to keep the title and bottom button on the screen, where there are a lot of recycler view items. In turn recycler view must fill all available place and don't overlap title and bottom button.

So, requirements for layout:

1. Title is always on the screen
2. Bottom button is always on the screen
3. Constraint layout must be scalable depending on the recycler view content (picture below)

The concept:
[image]

Layout which I have now

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:background="@color/yellow"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/constraint_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btnSave"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
        tools:itemCount="50" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/constraint_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result - recycler view isn't displayed
[image]

Perhaps there is another way to do this, but I spent a lot of time looking for a solution. I believe the solution should be simple, but I haven't found one yet.
DialogFragment doesn't fit here because this screen needs to be in full-screen mode when the app is in portrait orientation.

Comment: Did you found how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just constraint the bottom button (btnSave) as - `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rvList"`

Also don't fix the height of the recyclerView. Keep it as wrap_content

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I still have an issue with the recycler view which isn't displayed, when I set wrap_content for constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` on your `ContraintLayout`.

Comment: Yes, it helps, but it doesn't make a layout scalable by content height

Answer (score 0):

Try setting
`android:layout_height="0dp"` and `app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"`for the recycler view